# Using isset to display page content

Tags: php

I am having an issue using isset to display content on a page.

My PHP file is called messages.php

I am directing my users with links to this URL: `messages.php?inbox using if(isset($_GET['inbox']))`
 { } to display the users inbox. Same principle with the other users options such as compose message is: `messages.php?compose` again using isset

The only problem I have is that I cannot stop people from manually typing stuff like `domain.com/messages.php` or `domain.com/messages.php?somethingrandom.`

Is there a way to direct users to messages.php?inbox when they type in the address bar something that isnt assigned to isset?

I did try to use switch but couldnt seem to get it to work properly with how ive laid out my HTML.

An example of the whole file is here http://pastebin.com/SfqN2L7g

I am fairly new to PHP and think I may have gone down the complicated route.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `post` instead of `get`, generate a random token for each request, check if the user's logged in before doing so, since I assume it his inbox and so on. Tons of ways, take your pick.

Comment: Easy way: at the start of the file, check `if(get(one) || get(two) { OK } else { REDIRECT TO INBOX }`

Comment: Marcos Pérez Gude: Thank you for your advice. I have already tried this method but kept getting an error of 'The page isn't redirecting properly' on my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you added already would work, but I usually like having an array of `valid` options which I could maybe check against later on.

```
$validPages = array('inbox', 'compose');
$pageFound = false;

foreach ($validPages as $validPage) {
    if (isset($_GET[$validPage])) {
        $pageFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (! $pageFound) {
    header('Location: /messages.php?inbox');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Marcos Pérez Gude, the answer is as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['inbox']) || isset($_GET['compose'])){

//Then do below

 }else{
    header("Location: messages.php?inbox");
    exit;
}
```